# Coefficients in K2SO4 electrolysis scheme (textbook)

Tags: electrolysis

From a textbook, a scheme of $\ce{K2SO4}$ electrolysis:

[image]

I don't understand how the two equations with the coefficients 2 before the water combine into the equation with the coefficient 6. Would not the coefficient before $\ce{H2}$ be 1.5 then?

The text is

> When a salt consisting of an active metal and an oxygen-containing acid moiety is subjected to electrolysis, both cathode and anode participate in the electrolytic dissolution of water.

Comment: Multiply the first (left) equation by 2.

Comment: @IvanNeretin - would not I have then to multiply the second by 2 also, giving me 8H2O in the final reaction?

Comment: Nope. Remember, you want the whole thing to be balanced in electrons too.

Comment: @IvanNeretin - thank you! I see. The balancing goes around the $\ce{4e^-}$. I thought it was in order to make OH- and H+ to dovetail into water nicely, and forgot about electron balancing.

Comment: It seems to me that there is a typo in the first equation. It should be $$\ce{2H2O + 2e^- <=> H2 ^ + 2OH^-}$$

Comment: @MaxW - indeed, I had noticed that, but this is a minor typo - the only one that I've found so far in this particular textbook.